# Returning true if the current time is between two military times?

Tags: c#

I have a function here that attempts to return true if the current time is between two military times.

The issue here is finding a time between `2130` and `0700` is a little tricky. The `2130` works fine, but `0700` is before `2130`, so it returns false here. How can I get this to return true?

Just switch the `&&` to a `||`?

```
public bool IsSleeping()
{
    DateTime m_dt = DateTime.Now;
    string strMilitaryTime;
    int time;

    strMilitaryTime = m_dt.ToString("HHmm");    // Get current military time
    time = Convert.ToInt32(strMilitaryTime);    // Convert to int

    // The time must be between sleeping hours of 2400 and 0700.
    if (time >= 2130 && time < 700)
        return true; 

    return false;
}
```

Comment: "Military time" isn't a thing (or at least, it's a very Americano-centric term). I think you mean 24-hour clock notation, but what timezone?

Comment: *Just switch the '&&' to a '||'?* Please try it and see. Also you can just: `return (time >= 2130 && time < 700)`

Comment: Using integers is not ideal, use a `TimeSpan` to represent a time-of-day value.

Comment: Gilad, tried that initially. If you think of it, if time is 2300, it's not less than 700, so it will return false.

Comment: @Phil - with `||` it is enough that one of the statements is true :) so for `2300` it will be true for the first and thus return true. In any case Dai's recommendation of using `TimeSpan` is a good one

Comment: Oh, I was thinking you were using &&. With ||, that's fine. I'm liking the TimeSpan solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static Boolean IsSleeping()
{
    TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

    TimeSpan before = new TimeSpan(  7,  0, 0 );
    TimeSpan after  = new TimeSpan( 21, 30, 0 );

    return now < before || now > after;
}
```

Comment: Please don't dump "fixed" code, explain your approach and why that solves the problem.

Comment: It's very readable for me. Thanks! Though I would like to know if TimeOfDay returns a 24-hour time or not, but MSDN might answer that.